# preg_match allow blank string or up to 100 characters

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to validate postal addresses that'll be inserted into a database.

A user can either leave the addresses field blank, or enter up to 100 characters.

What is the right way to specify `blank to 100` characters in a regex?

This works: `preg_match('/^[a-z0-9\s]{0,100}$/i',$str)`, but I've also seen it done like this `preg_match('/^[a-z0-9\s]{,100}$/i',$str)`

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Better always define the lower and upper bounds, `{0,100}`. `{,100}` [does not work in PHP](https://3v4l.org/eQOKL) and it may cause undefined behavior in other regex engines.

Comment: Why can't you use a proper regexp to validate postal codes?

Comment: Aside: 100 characters *might not* be long enough for entire addresses - especially if you're likely to be dealing with University addresses - or possibly France (I've seen town names in French addresses pushing 30 characters alone).

Comment: @SalmanA ... that could involve knowing the exact structure for every postcode in the world and cross referencing them against the country in the address specified - which might not be a trivial task.

Comment: Addresses may also contain `. - '` and many letters different from `[a-z]`.